# Huge gap between items containing images in an unordered list in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, html-lists, internet-explorer-11, footer

For my footer I have a horizontal unordered list containing images (social media icons).
This works in all browsers (it also works in Edge), but it doesn't seem to work in IE11.

[image: Working as inteneded in Chrome]
Working as intended in Chrome

[image: Huge gaps between the icons in IE11]
Huge gap between the icons in IE11

I am not sure what is causing these spaces.

[Relevant jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1vptee23)

```css
footer{
text-align: right;
width: 100%;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 0;
background-color: #fff;
color: #000;
}

span#copyright{
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
float: left;
vertical-align: middle;
padding-left: 4.5px;
font-size: 1.8vh;
line-height: 2.9vh;
}

#socialmedia{
display: inline-block;
}

#socialmedia ul{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0; 
}

#socialmedia ul li{
display: inline;
}

footer a{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: text-top;
padding-right: 4.5px;
}

footer svg{
font-size: 0;
display: block;
fill: #000;
height: 2.9vh;
padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
<span id="copyright">&copy; Some name</span>
<div id="socialmedia">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" id="socialmedia-facebook">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M22.676 0H1.324C.593 0 0 .593 0 1.324v21.352C0 23.408.593 24 1.324 24h11.494v-9.294H9.689v-3.621h3.129V8.41c0-3.099 1.894-4.785 4.659-4.785 1.325 0 2.464.097 2.796.141v3.24h-1.921c-1.5 0-1.792.721-1.792 1.771v2.311h3.584l-.465 3.63H16.56V24h6.115c.733 0 1.325-.592 1.325-1.324V1.324C24 .593 23.408 0 22.676 0"></path>
</svg>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="socialmedia-twitter">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/>
</svg>
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" id="socialmedia-instagram">
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
<path d="M12 0C8.74 0 8.333.015 7.053.072 5.775.132 4.905.333 4.14.63c-.789.306-1.459.717-2.126 1.384S.935 3.35.63 4.14C.333 4.905.131 5.775.072 7.053.012 8.333 0 8.74 0 12s.015 3.667.072 4.947c.06 1.277.261 2.148.558 2.913.306.788.717 1.459 1.384 2.126.667.666 1.336 1.079 2.126 1.384.766.296 1.636.499 2.913.558C8.333 23.988 8.74 24 12 24s3.667-.015 4.947-.072c1.277-.06 2.148-.262 2.913-.558.788-.306 1.459-.718 2.126-1.384.666-.667 1.079-1.335 1.384-2.126.296-.765.499-1.636.558-2.913.06-1.28.072-1.687.072-4.947s-.015-3.667-.072-4.947c-.06-1.277-.262-2.149-.558-2.913-.306-.789-.718-1.459-1.384-2.126C21.319 1.347 20.651.935 19.86.63c-.765-.297-1.636-.499-2.913-.558C15.667.012 15.26 0 12 0zm0 2.16c3.203 0 3.585.016 4.85.071 1.17.055 1.805.249 2.227.415.562.217.96.477 1.382.896.419.42.679.819.896 1.381.164.422.36 1.057.413 2.227.057 1.266.07 1.646.07 4.85s-.015 3.585-.074 4.85c-.061 1.17-.256 1.805-.421 2.227-.224.562-.479.96-.899 1.382-.419.419-.824.679-1.38.896-.42.164-1.065.36-2.235.413-1.274.057-1.649.07-4.859.07-3.211 0-3.586-.015-4.859-.074-1.171-.061-1.816-.256-2.236-.421-.569-.224-.96-.479-1.379-.899-.421-.419-.69-.824-.9-1.38-.165-.42-.359-1.065-.42-2.235-.045-1.26-.061-1.649-.061-4.844 0-3.196.016-3.586.061-4.861.061-1.17.255-1.814.42-2.234.21-.57.479-.96.9-1.381.419-.419.81-.689 1.379-.898.42-.166 1.051-.361 2.221-.421 1.275-.045 1.65-.06 4.859-.06l.045.03zm0 3.678c-3.405 0-6.162 2.76-6.162 6.162 0 3.405 2.76 6.162 6.162 6.162 3.405 0 6.162-2.76 6.162-6.162 0-3.405-2.76-6.162-6.162-6.162zM12 16c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4 4 1.79 4 4-1.79 4-4 4zm7.846-10.405c0 .795-.646 1.44-1.44 1.44-.795 0-1.44-.646-1.44-1.44 0-.794.646-1.439 1.44-1.439.793-.001 1.44.645 1.44 1.439z"/>
</svg>
</a>
</li>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain what the exact issue is, but adding a width and height attribute to the SVG improves it alot. The only slight difference is when it's scaled by height.

If you change:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24">
```

to

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
```

Adding the width and height attribute improves it. Although the cost is some slight spacing when it's scaled down.

Here's an example:

```css
footer{
 text-align: right;
 width: 100%;
 padding-top: 3px;
 padding-bottom: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
}

span#copyright{
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 float: left;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding-left: 4.5px;
 font-size: 1.8vh;
 line-height: 2.9vh;
}

#socialmedia{
 display: inline-block;
}

#socialmedia ul{
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0; 
}

#socialmedia ul li{
 display: inline;
}

footer a{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: text-top;
 padding-right: 4.5px;
}

footer svg{
 font-size: 0;
 display: block;
 fill: #000;
 height: 2.9vh;
 padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <span id="copyright">&copy; Some name</span>
  <div id="socialmedia">
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="socialmedia-facebook">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
       <path d="M22.676 0H1.324C.593 0 0 .593 0 1.324v21.352C0 23.408.593 24 1.324 24h11.494v-9.294H9.689v-3.621h3.129V8.41c0-3.099 1.894-4.785 4.659-4.785 1.325 0 2.464.097 2.796.141v3.24h-1.921c-1.5 0-1.792.721-1.792 1.771v2.311h3.584l-.465 3.63H16.56V24h6.115c.733 0 1.325-.592 1.325-1.324V1.324C24 .593 23.408 0 22.676 0"></path>
      </svg>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="socialmedia-twitter">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
       <path d="M23.954 4.569c-.885.389-1.83.654-2.825.775 1.014-.611 1.794-1.574 2.163-2.723-.951.555-2.005.959-3.127 1.184-.896-.959-2.173-1.559-3.591-1.559-2.717 0-4.92 2.203-4.92 4.917 0 .39.045.765.127 1.124C7.691 8.094 4.066 6.13 1.64 3.161c-.427.722-.666 1.561-.666 2.475 0 1.71.87 3.213 2.188 4.096-.807-.026-1.566-.248-2.228-.616v.061c0 2.385 1.693 4.374 3.946 4.827-.413.111-.849.171-1.296.171-.314 0-.615-.03-.916-.086.631 1.953 2.445 3.377 4.604 3.417-1.68 1.319-3.809 2.105-6.102 2.105-.39 0-.779-.023-1.17-.067 2.189 1.394 4.768 2.209 7.557 2.209 9.054 0 13.999-7.496 13.999-13.986 0-.209 0-.42-.015-.63.961-.689 1.8-1.56 2.46-2.548l-.047-.02z"/>
      </svg>
     </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#" id="socialmedia-instagram">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24" height="24">
       <path d="M12 0C8.74 0 8.333.015 7.053.072 5.775.132 4.905.333 4.14.63c-.789.306-1.459.717-2.126 1.384S.935 3.35.63 4.14C.333 4.905.131 5.775.072 7.053.012 8.333 0 8.74 0 12s.015 3.667.072 4.947c.06 1.277.261 2.148.558 2.913.306.788.717 1.459 1.384 2.126.667.666 1.336 1.079 2.126 1.384.766.296 1.636.499 2.913.558C8.333 23.988 8.74 24 12 24s3.667-.015 4.947-.072c1.277-.06 2.148-.262 2.913-.558.788-.306 1.459-.718 2.126-1.384.666-.667 1.079-1.335 1.384-2.126.296-.765.499-1.636.558-2.913.06-1.28.072-1.687.072-4.947s-.015-3.667-.072-4.947c-.06-1.277-.262-2.149-.558-2.913-.306-.789-.718-1.459-1.384-2.126C21.319 1.347 20.651.935 19.86.63c-.765-.297-1.636-.499-2.913-.558C15.667.012 15.26 0 12 0zm0 2.16c3.203 0 3.585.016 4.85.071 1.17.055 1.805.249 2.227.415.562.217.96.477 1.382.896.419.42.679.819.896 1.381.164.422.36 1.057.413 2.227.057 1.266.07 1.646.07 4.85s-.015 3.585-.074 4.85c-.061 1.17-.256 1.805-.421 2.227-.224.562-.479.96-.899 1.382-.419.419-.824.679-1.38.896-.42.164-1.065.36-2.235.413-1.274.057-1.649.07-4.859.07-3.211 0-3.586-.015-4.859-.074-1.171-.061-1.816-.256-2.236-.421-.569-.224-.96-.479-1.379-.899-.421-.419-.69-.824-.9-1.38-.165-.42-.359-1.065-.42-2.235-.045-1.26-.061-1.649-.061-4.844 0-3.196.016-3.586.061-4.861.061-1.17.255-1.814.42-2.234.21-.57.479-.96.9-1.381.419-.419.81-.689 1.379-.898.42-.166 1.051-.361 2.221-.421 1.275-.045 1.65-.06 4.859-.06l.045.03zm0 3.678c-3.405 0-6.162 2.76-6.162 6.162 0 3.405 2.76 6.162 6.162 6.162 3.405 0 6.162-2.76 6.162-6.162 0-3.405-2.76-6.162-6.162-6.162zM12 16c-2.21 0-4-1.79-4-4s1.79-4 4-4 4 1.79 4 4-1.79 4-4 4zm7.846-10.405c0 .795-.646 1.44-1.44 1.44-.795 0-1.44-.646-1.44-1.44 0-.794.646-1.439 1.44-1.439.793-.001 1.44.645 1.44 1.439z"/>
      </svg>
     </a>
    </li>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below css style can help you solve the issue::

```
span#copyright {
  float: left;
}

#socialmedia {
  float: right;
}
```

And just add a clearfix to footer div as per the below code::

```
footer::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```